# Dynamically create variables based on character vector and evaluation of numeric vector against variable in R

Tags: r, variables, dplyr

Working on a script to parse SARS-CoV-2 sequencing results for import to our Laboratory information system. Need to test if nucleotide positions for key mutations are included in the consensus sequence data. Data on missing nucleotide sequences positions is included as a comma separated string variable, where ranges are separated by "-".
I thought Id write a for loop that tests each key nucleotide positition for a specifik mutation against the missing data defined in the string variable.
So far:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Create test data

```
subs <- as.character(c("A", "B", "C", "D"))
subs_pos <- as.numeric(c("1", "30","22700", "13500"))
df <- data.frame("id" = letters[1:5], 
                 "missing" = as.character(c("1-13030,13364-13626,13962-15504,15862-26543,26891-29904",
                                            "1-29,21717,29727-29777,29837-29904",
                                            "19276-19571,22627-22822,29837-29904",
                                            "29837-29904",
                                            "1-10,20-30"
                                            )))
```

data frame:

```
id                                                 missing
1  a 1-13030,13364-13626,13962-15504,15862-26543,26891-29904
2  b                      1-29,21717,29727-29777,29837-29904
3  c                     19276-19571,22627-22822,29837-29904
4  d                                             29837-29904
5  e                                              1-10,20-30
```

for loop

```
for(i in seq_along(subs)) { 
  new_var = as.character(subs[i])
  print(new_var)
  nn = as.numeric(subs_pos[i])
  print(nn)
  df <- df %>% 
    mutate(!!new_var := ifelse(!!nn %in%
                               as.numeric(
                                 source(textConnection(paste("c(", gsub("\\-", ":", missing),")")))$value), "I", "N"))
}
```

Print on screen and resulting data frame:

```
>[1] "A"
>[1] 1
>[1] "B"
>[1] 30
>[1] "C"
>[1] 22700
>[1] "D"
>[1] 13500
> df
>  id                                                 missing A B C D
>1  a 1-13030,13364-13626,13962-15504,15862-26543,26891-29904 I I N N
>2  b                      1-29,21717,29727-29777,29837-29904 I I N N
>3  c                     19276-19571,22627-22822,29837-29904 I I N N
>4  d                                             29837-29904 I I N N
>5  e                                              1-10,20-30 I I N N
```

Expected data frame:

```
> id                                                 missing A B C D
> 1  a 1-13030,13364-13626,13962-15504,15862-26543,26891-29904 I I N I
> 2  b                      1-29,21717,29727-29777,29837-29904 I N N N
> 3  c                     19276-19571,22627-22822,29837-29904 N N I N
> 4  d                                             29837-29904 N N N N
> 5  e                                              1-10,20-30 I I N N
```

If run on for one instance the test works

```
> 13500 %in% as.numeric(source(textConnection(paste("c(", gsub("\\-", ":", df$missing[1]),")")))$value)
[1] TRUE
```

I seems that my code results in the results of last evaluation to run is applied to all rows in the data frame. I've confirmed this by changing the test data.

Answer (score 0):

We could split the 'missing' by `,` to expand the rows, create new columns 'start', 'stop' by splitting at delimiter `-` ('df1')

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 <- df %>%
       separate_rows(missing, sep = ",") %>%
       separate(missing, into = c('start', 'stop'), convert = TRUE)
```

Now, we use the OP's method to create new columns with 'subs' vector

```
for(i in seq_along(subs)) {
     df1 <- df1 %>%
          mutate(!! subs[i] :=  case_when(!is.na(stop) &
           start <= subs_pos[i] &  stop >= subs_pos[i] ~ 'I', TRUE ~'N'))
 
 }
```

Grouped by 'id', `summarise` the 'subs' columns to return 'I' if there is any 'I' or else 'N', do a join with the original data and `select` the columns in the order we want

```
df1 %>% 
     group_by(id) %>% 
     summarise(across(c(A:D), ~ case_when('I' %in% . ~ 'I', 
            TRUE ~ 'N'))) %>% 
     right_join(df) %>%
     select(names(df), everything())
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 6
#  id    missing                                                 A     B     C     D    
#  <chr> <chr>                                                   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 a     1-13030,13364-13626,13962-15504,15862-26543,26891-29904 I     I     I     I    
#2 b     1-29,21717,29727-29777,29837-29904                      I     N     N     N    
#3 c     19276-19571,22627-22822,29837-29904                     N     N     I     N    
#4 d     29837-29904                                             N     N     N     N    
#5 e     1-10,20-30                                              I     I     N     N
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, suggested by a colleague:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  ranges <- as.numeric(source(textConnection(paste("c(", gsub("\\-", ":", df$missing[i]),")")))$value)
  for(j in 1:length(subs)){
    if(subs_pos[j] %in% ranges) {
      df[i,][subs[j]] <- "I"
    }
  }
}
```

}